# Extracting positional characters from each line in a text file

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a text file with multiple order numbers, one per line. Each order is 10 chars in length, the 1st character is always a "1" and the "Store number" is 4-digits long, and always starts from the 2nd character e.g. 1054003863, so "0540" is the store number, followed by 1171 and then 2957.

```
1054003863
1117103803
1295704378
```

I am trying to extract the store number from each line in this text file into a variable, and then perform a task based on that variable. Here is one of the attempts that I have made to get this working:

```
$OrderList = Get-Content C:\temp\myorders.txt 
Foreach ($Order in $OrderList)
{
$StoreNumber = $Order | Select-object {$_.Remove(4,6)}
.
.
then the rest of the script before moving to the next element in the array
}
```

Comment: Wait, wouldn't the store number in the first line be "0540"?

Comment: Yes you are right - my mistake

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the first character and on the new string everything behind the fourth:

```
Get-Content 'C:\temp\myorders.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $StoreNumber = $_.Remove(0, 1).Remove(4)
}
```

**Result**:

```
0540
1171
2957
```

---

If you need to skip the second character if its a `0`, you could also do this with a `regex`:

```
^\d0?(\d{4})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**PowerShell:**

```
Get-Content 'C:\temp\myorders.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $StoreNumber = [regex]::Match($_, '^\d0?(\d{4})').Groups[1].Value
}
```

**Result**:

```
5400
1171
2957
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is using the fact that PowerShell is implemented in .NET, so you have easy access to all .NET methods. A PowerShell string can access its [.NET methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) just like in C# or VB.NET with the `.`-operator. For example `"1054003863".Substring(2,4)` yields `5400`.

So the line you are looking for would be

```
$StoreNumber = $Order.Substring(2,4)
```

based on your example, where the store number starts at the 3rd position. If it starts on the second position, just use `$Order.Substring(1,4)`.

Extra tip (unrelated to your specific problem): You can also use the so called static methods of a .NET type by using the typename like this:

```
[System.Math]::Sqrt(2)
```

yields the square root of 2. `System.Math` is the typename and `Sqrt` is the static method. [Here](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2015/02/09/useful-static-net-methods.aspx) are some examples for useful static methods.

Happy coding!

Comment: Hi, I tried '$StoreNumber = $Order.Substring(2,4)' originally, but kept getting and error: "Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Substring'."